# Is there a way to hide all particles in a scene?

Tags: particles, workflow, shortcut

Pretty straightforward, I am looking for an option or key command to hide all the particle systems in the current scene. Is this possible or do I need to write a script?

Answer (score 2):

Via script it would looks like this:

```
import bpy
for object in bpy.data.objects:
    if bpy.context.scene in object.users_scene:
        try:
            for modifier in object.modifiers:
                if modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM':
                    modifier.show_viewport = False
        except:
            pass
```

And to redisplay all particle systems in the scene:

```
import bpy
for object in bpy.data.objects:
    if bpy.context.scene in object.users_scene:
        try:
            for modifier in object.modifiers:
                if modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM':
                    modifier.show_viewport = True
        except:
            pass
```